# Code fix for decode in Informix

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, informix

I am using a decode function in Informix database. I am retrieving a field which is an integer datatype. If the value I retrieved is `''` then I need to set it as null; if not I am setting the same value.

I tried like this:

```
decode(table1.field1,'',NULL,table1.field1)
```

but I am getting the following error

> Corresponding types must be compatible in CASE expression.

I am confused how the value will be retrieved from database — as null or as 0 or -1 or something. Do I need to do like this?

```
decode(table1.field1,'',0,table1.field1)
```

how to resolve it

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion here.  Since `table1.field1` is an INTEGER column, it will not ever contain an empty string.  It will either contain NULL or a valid INTEGER value; so the update is not needed at all.

Why do you think that you might be getting `''`?  You'd have to be selecting the INTEGER column into a string variable — if your programming languages distinguishes types.  Otherwise, the chances are that the empty string is the way your programming language represents nulls.

Comment: i have used outer join due to which i am getting "" values in select query. However, i have resolved it using case statement. thank you.